# Send Pipeline Error 0xc0c01658

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I created a Send Pipeline that has a Flat File Assembler. When I tried to send the Message I am getting error like, Error Code 0xc0c01658 (Send Pipeline Error)

The detail of the error:

> Please verify that the pipeline strong name is correct and that the pipeline assembly is in the GAC

Can anyone help me? I am new to BizTalk and I am learning

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you did restart your hosts after installation?

Comment: This can happen easily (and intermittently) in multi-server environments where the deployment has not gone out to all servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see that the Pipeline is in the GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL)
There should be a folder there with the Assembly name (Jax.Dhana.SamplePRJ), and then a sub folder which will be in the format of .NetVersion_DLLVersion_PublicKey e.g. v4.0_1.0.0.0_cf96c3b300e6dd40 and under that should be the DLL.  If the Name, Assembly Version Number or Public Key do not match then it will not be able to find it in the GAC.

Comment: I did check the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL. The sub folder is having name in the same format v4.0_1.0.0.0_cf96c3b300e6dd40

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the existing assembly in `gac using gacutil -u` and then reinstall the latest assembly.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have added the pipeline to BizTalk using add resource, or try doing it again anyway.

Comment: I tried by adding resources too, but I am finding the same error.

Comment: not sure if you restarted the host instance after add resource. If you did, then looks like your error message is cut, can you go to event viewer and find the complete error. Are you using a custom pipeline component?

Comment: I created a new project again and tried doing it worked, I dont know what mistake or error I did earlier. Thanks for the help